# .htacess rewrite url not working for php files, but works for html files

Tags: php, .htaccess, digital-ocean

I'm using LAMP stack and already configured apache2 to rewrite url. Below is my .htaccess file

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^page$ page.php [NC]
```

Above code rewrite /contact to /contact.html and works fine. But, the same did not work for /page -> page.php

Is there anything I missed out? By the way, I am using DigitalOcean (in case it has anything to do with it :) !).

Comment: Hi, try to access the URL `/page.php` to see if it gives you something.

Comment: @ankabot yes the url is accessible.. contents are displaying

Comment: No idea then, I tested your code in my environment and it worked..

Comment: @ankabot it worked on my local system too, worked on AWS EC2 instance as well..

Comment: Your directive matches `/pages` (with an `s`), not `/page` (no `s`) - as stated in your question?!

Comment: @MrWhite didn't work with /pages either .. edited the directive

Comment: What happens exactly? Do you just get a 404 saying that `/page` doesn't exist? Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Try the following: `RewriteRule ^foo$ page.php [L]` and request `/foo` instead - does it now serve `/page.php`?

Comment: @MrWhite , yes, i got the 404 message .  Will try out that.

Comment: Is that the entirety of your `.htaccess` file or are there more directives?

Answer (score 0):

Configure in:

```
 /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Search `.htacess`
 and remove the `#` from:

```
# AllowOverride
```

It controls what directives may be placed in `.htaccess` files.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the flag !!!
try an other flag : RewriteRule ^(.*)$ bootstrap.php?app=Frontend [QSA,L].

Comment: And what is that going to do? (The rest of your directive is also completely irrelevant to the question?!)